# Downloading Geany for El Capitan

Tags: macos, installation, osx-elcapitan, geany

I just started using OSX, I am somewhat more familiar with Ubuntu and Fedora. I am trying to install Geany and I was successful in doing so but it isn't recognizing the command. I used homebrew to install it and it is showing that it is available in my applications as Geany.app but I can't seem to find the icon.

Answer (score 1):

There is a native Geany build for MacOS X available to [download from the webpage](http://www.geany.org/Download/Releases#macOSXBinaries).

To start Geany on MacOS on default the easiest way is to use Cmd + Space and type Geany. For more questions about MacOS I however recommend to check https://apple.stackexchange.com/